# Derefencing nullptr warning in c++

Tags: pointers, c++14, warnings, autosar

```
if (nullptr!=timing_info)
{
   timing_info->h = start_time;
}
```

I get the following warning

```
autosar_cpp14 a5-1-1 violation
Using literal "NULL" other than type initialization, where symbolic names shall be used instead.
```

The autosar rule a5-1-1 reads

> Rule A5-1-1 (required, implementation, partially automated) Literal
>   values shall not be used apart from type initialization, otherwise
>   symbolic names shall be used instead.

I never thought "nullptr" was a literal value. If it is a literal value, then what is the best way to handle this warning.

Comment: I have no clue what autosar is, but does `if (timing_info)` remove the warning? It literally does the same thing, but who knows... `nullptr` is a literal value, yes.

Comment: when I simply use ´´´ if (timing_info) ´´´, I get warning, the if statement is only suppposed to handle boolean statements. So I can't do that as well.

Comment: how is nullptr defined?

Comment: Would it work, if you change the condition to `if (timing_info != nullptr)`? BTW. searching through the AR document, I even found a similar statement than yours, and it was neither marked with compliant or non-compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already quoted, `Rule A5-1-1` says

> Rule A5-1-1 (required, implementation, partially automated)Literal
>   values shall not be used apart from type initialization,
>   otherwise symbolic names shall be used instead.

[(source)](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/17-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf)

The idea behind this rule is that you should not use [magic constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants), i.e., don't write something like

```
// 100 is a magic constant. It's not clear what the next line means without comments.
if (list.size() > 100) {
  std::cout << "error!";
} else {
  std::cout << "everything ok!";
}
```

but rather, write

```
static constexpr auto maximum_allowed_size = 100;
// The next line speaks for itself: "if list is bigger than allowed ..."
if (list.size() > maximum_allowed_size) {
  std::cout << "error!";
} else {
  std::cout << "everything ok!";
}
```

This extra constant increases readability in most cases.
[Since `nullptr` is a literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) and you use that literal `nullptr` for something else than "type initialization", your code violates that rule A5-1-1.

I don't know if autosar intentionally discourages the use of literal `nullptr`, I personally don't see a reason why one should do this. Maybe it has been overseen (should be an exception).

You can rephrase your code to silence the checker:

```
if (timing_info)  // implicitly convert pointer to bool
```

as that variant apparently makes the checker unhappy, too, here is another variant:

```
if (!!timing_info)  // convert pointer to bool using double negation
```

You could also use casts, but I wouldn't do that. Frankly speaking, I like the original variant (`if (nullptr != timing_info)`) most.